# Error because of language(?) in Sharepoint.PNP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a Powershell script that has this strange behaviour: When I run it it works fine, but when another colleague of mine does it, it gives an error. The command is this:

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission -List "Library" -identity "/sites/xxxx/Library/Folder" -User "user@acme.com" -AddRole "Edit"
```

The error is:

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission : Cannot locate the level of permission.
At line:226 char:1
+ Set-PnPfolderPermission -List "Library" -identity "/si ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-PnPFolderPermission], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.SetFolderPermission
```

and if I change the `-AddRole` switch to `-AddRole "Editar"` (this is Edit in Portuguese!) it works for him.

I would like to put it to work for both of us. What should I do?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, the role name for this cmdlet needs to accord with the current language used by the user. Adding another preference language in Delve will not help. I tried to get the name of the role via getting another user with edit permission, however not work well.

```
$roles=get-pnproledefinition
$name=($roles|where RoleTypeKind -eq 'Editor').Name
```

Still you can have a try with it. And I will suggest you to post in the [github](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell) about this behavior for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I will...